# Treating a vector as a function on its indices/applying this function to another vector (of indices)

Tags: matlab

Let `y=[4;6;2;9;5;1]` be a column vector and let `i=[4,2,1]` be a vector of indices. I would like to somehow "apply" i to y and obtain `[9,6,4]`. Or at least `[4;2;0;9;0;0]`.

There is clearly a way to do this with a for loop. I was advised by someone on this site never to use a for loop in MATLAB. Is there some logical operator I can use here? Ideally one could treat y as a function on its indices and apply y to i *as a function*. Is this possible, or should I go with the old reliable for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
y(i)
```

returns your result `[9 6 4]`.

To set all the elements that are not part of the index-list to zero, you can copy the specified elements:

```
out = zeros(size(y));
out(i) = y(i);
```

Comment: I swore I tried that and it didn't work, but I obviously didn't do that right. Thank you.